# How can I debug external python package in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have downloaded python package from the web (e.g., github).

The usage is via CLI, for example:

`python functionality.py opt1 opt2`

Since I want to understand what is going on under the hood in `functionality.py` 
I want to be able to debug it line by line.
How can I achieve that using PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not writing a comment, but I don't have the right.

You could use the package in a simple script (import it). Afterwards, press CTRL+LEFT CLICK on the function/class that you have used in order to see the source code. Now you can put breakpoints my clicking on the space near the line number[image: Breakpoints set]. The red point indicates that a breakpoint is put. 
You can run your script in debug mode using the debugger from the menu up right (second icon) and see what's happening. [image]

Comment: the script is stand alone, how can I run it so it will hit the breakpoint?

Comment: create a project and add the .py. Now open the script and put a breakpoint on it. If you have a project already created for something else and your script is only a file, you could simply create a scratch file (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Insert), add the code, put the breakpoints and run it in debugging.